# How can I get the width of a wx.ListCtrl and its column name?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, width, listctrl

I'm working in wx.Python and I want to get the columns of my wx.ListCtrl to auto-resize i.e. to be at minimum the width of the column name and otherwise as wide as the widest element or its column name.  At first I thought the ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin might do this but it doesn't so it looks like I might have to do it myself (Please correct me if there's a built in way of doing this!!!)

How can I find out how wide the titles and elements of my list will be rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would have to make this yourself for wx.ListCtrl and I'm not sure it would be easy (or elegant) to do right.

Consider using a wx.Grid, here is a small example to get you going:

```
import wx, wx.grid

class GridData(wx.grid.PyGridTableBase):
    _cols = "This is a long column name,b,c".split(",")
    _data = [
        "1 2 3".split(),
        "4,5,And here is a long cell value".split(","),
        "7 8 9".split()
    ]

    def GetColLabelValue(self, col):
        return self._cols[col]

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def GetNumberCols(self):
        return len(self._cols)

    def GetValue(self, row, col):
        return self._data[row][col]


class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.SetTable(GridData())
        grid.EnableEditing(False)
        grid.SetSelectionMode(wx.grid.Grid.SelectRows)
        grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        grid.AutoSizeColumns()


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = Test()
app.TopWindow.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to jakepars answer: this should check, whether the header is bigger, or the item which takes the most space in the column. Not to elegant but working...

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        items = ['A', 'b', 'something really REALLY long']
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        for item in items:
            self.list.InsertStringItem(0, item)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
        a = self.list.GetColumnWidth(0)
        print "a " + str(a)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(0,wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER)
        b = self.list.GetColumnWidth(0)
        print "b " + str(b)
        if a>b:
            print "a is bigger"
            self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)
app = wx.App(False)
frm = Frame(None, title="ListCtrl test")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to save yourself a lot of headache related to wx.ListCtrl you should switch over to using [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/) (has a nice cookbook and forum for code examples).  It's very nice and I tend to use it for anything more than a very basic ListCtrl, because it is extremely powerful and flexible and easy to code up.  Here's [the wxPyWiki page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ObjectListView) related to it (including example code).  The developer is also on the wxPython mailing list so you can email with questions.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        items = ['A', 'b', 'something really REALLY long']
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "AA")
        for item in items:
            self.list.InsertStringItem(0, item)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)

app = wx.App(False)
frm = Frame(None, title="ListCtrl test")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I think you want wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER -- otherwise it doesn't consider the column header text, just the text of the data values.